# Unable to resolve exception in Azure Active Directory code

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to execute below code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Graph.Core;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;


namespace AzureActiveDirectory
{
    class Program
    {


        //3. Copy the following code as is to your application.

        // Register your app on the Azure AD application registration portal 
        // Remember to :
        // 1. Check the redirect uri starting with "msal"
        // 2. Set "Treat application as public client" to "Yes"
        const string clientId = "XXXXXX";
        const string tenant = "XXXXX";

        const string redirectUri = "http://localhost";




        // Change the following between each call to create/update user if not deleting the user
        private static string givenName = "test99";
    private static string surname = "user99";

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            // Initialize and prepare MSAL
            //What we want to do 

            // string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read", "user.readwrite.all" };

            string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
            IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}"))
            .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
            .Build();

        // Initialize the Graph SDK authentication provider
        InteractiveAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new InteractiveAuthenticationProvider(app, scopes);
        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

        // Get information from Graph about the currently signed-In user
        Console.WriteLine("--Fetching details of the currently signed-in user--");
        GetMeAsync(graphServiceClient).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine("---------");

        // Create a new user
        Console.WriteLine($"--Creating a new user in the tenant '{tenant}'--");
        User newUser = CreateUserAsync(graphServiceClient).Result;
        PrintUserDetails(newUser);
        Console.WriteLine("---------");

        // Update an existing user
        if (newUser != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--Updating the detail of an existing user--");
            User updatedUser = UpdateUserAsync(graphServiceClient, userId: newUser.Id, jobTitle: "Program Manager").Result;
            PrintUserDetails(updatedUser);
            Console.WriteLine("---------");
        }

        // List existing users
        Console.WriteLine("--Listing all users in the tenant--");
        List<User> users = GetUsersAsync(graphServiceClient).Result;
        users.ForEach(u => PrintUserDetails(u));
        Console.WriteLine("---------");

        // Delete this user
        Console.WriteLine("--Deleting a user in the tenant--");
        if (newUser != null)
        {
            DeleteUserAsync(graphServiceClient, newUser?.Id).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); ;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("---------");

        // List existing users after deletion
        Console.WriteLine("--Listing all users in the tenant after deleting a user.--");
        users = GetUsersAsync(graphServiceClient).Result;
        users.ForEach(u => PrintUserDetails(u));
        Console.WriteLine("---------");

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }



    private static async Task GetMeAsync(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
    {
        // Call /me Api
        var me = await graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
        Console.WriteLine($"Display Name from /me->{me.DisplayName}");

        var directreports = await graphServiceClient.Me.DirectReports.Request().GetAsync();

        foreach (User user in directreports.CurrentPage)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Report's Display Name ->{user.DisplayName}");
        }
    }


    private static async Task<User> CreateUserAsync(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
    {
        User newUserObject = null;

        string displayname = $"{givenName} {surname}";
        string mailNickName = $"{givenName}{surname}";
        string upn = $"{mailNickName}{tenant}";
        string password = "p@$$w0rd!";

        try
        {

            newUserObject = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(new User
            {
                AccountEnabled = true,
                DisplayName = displayname,
                MailNickname = mailNickName,
                GivenName = givenName,
                Surname = surname,
                PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
                {
                    Password = password
                },
                UserPrincipalName = upn
            });
        }
        catch (ServiceException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("We could not add a new user: " + e.Error.Message);
            return null;
        }

        return newUserObject;
    }


    private static void PrintUserDetails(User user)
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"DisplayName-{user.DisplayName}, MailNickname- {user.MailNickname}, GivenName-{user.GivenName}, Surname-{user.Surname}, Upn-{user.UserPrincipalName}, JobTitle-{user.JobTitle}, Id-{user.Id}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The provided User is null!");
        }
    }



    private static async Task<User> UpdateUserAsync(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, string userId, string jobTitle)
    {
        User updatedUser = null;
        try
        {

            // Update the user.
            updatedUser = await graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Request().UpdateAsync(new User
            {
                JobTitle = jobTitle
            });
        }
        catch (ServiceException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"We could not update details of the user with Id {userId}: " + $"{e}");
        }

        return updatedUser;
    }


    private static async Task<List<User>> GetUsersAsync(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
    {
        List<User> allUsers = new List<User>();

        try
        {

            IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().Top(5).GetAsync();

            // When paginating
            //while(users.NextPageRequest != null)
            //{
            //    users = await users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
            //}

            if (users?.CurrentPage.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (User user in users)
                {
                    allUsers.Add(user);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ServiceException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("We could not retrieve the user's list: " + $"{e}");
            return null;
        }

        return allUsers;
    }


    private static async Task DeleteUserAsync(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, string userId)
    {
        try
        {
            await graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Request().DeleteAsync();
        }
        catch (ServiceException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"We could not delete the user with Id-{userId}: " + $"{e}");
        }
    }
}
}
```

After providing access to app during execution , i got below exception:

Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: generalException
Message: An error occurred sending the request.
'

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at GetMeAsync(graphServiceClient).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Please help.

---

Shortest code to reproduce problem.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Graph.Core;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;


namespace AzureActiveDirectory
{
    class Program
    {


        //3. Copy the following code as is to your application.

        // Register your app on the Azure AD application registration portal 
        // Remember to :
        // 1. Check the redirect uri starting with "msal"
        // 2. Set "Treat application as public client" to "Yes"
        const string clientId = "XXXXXX";
        const string tenant = "XXXXX";

        const string redirectUri = "http://localhost";




        // Change the following between each call to create/update user if not deleting the user
        private static string givenName = "test99";
    private static string surname = "user99";

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            // Initialize and prepare MSAL
            //What we want to do 

            // string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read", "user.readwrite.all" };

            string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
            IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}"))
            .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
            .Build();

        // Initialize the Graph SDK authentication provider
        InteractiveAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new InteractiveAuthenticationProvider(app, scopes);
        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

        // Get information from Graph about the currently signed-In user
        Console.WriteLine("--Fetching details of the currently signed-in user--");
        GetMeAsync(graphServiceClient).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine("---------");

        // Create a new user


        Console.WriteLine("---------");

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }





    private static async Task GetMeAsync(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
    {
        // Call /me Api
        var me = await graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
        Console.WriteLine($"Display Name from /me->{me.DisplayName}");

        var directreports = await graphServiceClient.Me.DirectReports.Request().GetAsync();

        foreach (User user in directreports.CurrentPage)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Report's Display Name ->{user.DisplayName}");
        }
    }



}
}
```

[image: value of graphServiceClient during debug]

[image]

Comment: When you place a breakpoint which line does this happen on?  A null reference exception means that you're attempting to use an object that had not been initialized.

Comment: `GetMeAsync` doesn't return anything.

Comment: // Get information from Graph about the currently signed-In user
        GetMeAsync(graphServiceClient).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
This is the line , but i can see that graphServiceClient params are populated with values like BatchUrl "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0"                                                            yes,getMeAsync doesn't return anything ,just before this line app is redirected to  logging in to app, and authentication is successful but finally exception thrown .

Comment: @AllTech `GetResult()` throws a NRE when there is no result to get.  Your method does not return anything.

Comment: Yes, i am also trying to find the same thing .   Attached 2 more screenshot of value of  graphServiceClient during debug.

Comment: I'm able to run you code without any exceptions. Can you please start removing parts of the code until you've narrowed it down to the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem? See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, i have edited my post and posted the shortest code in bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **interactive flow** is used by **mobile applications (Xamarin and UWP) and desktops applications** to call Microsoft Graph in the name of a user. Please go to Azure portal to check if you have added the correct platform.

[image]

The code works fine.

[image]